# C# Multiple columns for a record in a list box

Tags: c#, listbox

I want to display multiple records with multiple columns in a windows form, I have been trying to use listboxes.
This is how I'd like to display the data:
[image]

(Sorry for the large image)

Is there an easy way of doing this? Listboxes seem to only support multi columns for horizontal scrolling purposes

Comment: why not a grid instead for ListBox?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the ListView: you can set the View property to View.Details and you will get support for multi-columns. See this documentation from MSDN:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.view(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Use the DataGridView control for what you are trying to achieve.
There is a beginners tutorial you may want to refer to
http://www.dotnetperls.com/datagridview-tutorial